# How do I configure Visual Studio to see a net.tcp URL on local IIS?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, nettcpbinding

I've got a WCF service using the `netTcpBinding`, and no other binding. It works great when I manually deploy the files to IIS, and my client application can consume the service when I enter the `net.tcp://localhost(etc)` url. Now I'm trying to get the project to run in Visual Studio, so I can have the service and client in the same solution, and reference the service directly instead of going through IIS, and having to redeploy files manually.

Neither IIS Express nor the Visual Studio Development Server can use net.tcp, so they're out. In the Web tab of my service project, the "Use Local IIS Web Server" or "Use Custom Web Server" looked like good options, but neither of them will accept a URL that doesn't begin with http.

Is there some way of making my WCF service use IIS, and having my client reference the service directly (so that I don't have to deploy files to IIS, and then update service reference, every time I compile)?

Comment: Isn't the question how do you host a net.tcp service in IIS?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Not really; the service is hosted in IIS currently. I am just having trouble getting Visual Studio to acknowledge that service since it's rejecting the address.

Comment: As an experiment, create a WCF Service Library project and notice how it behaves when you press F5. It is hosted by the WCF Service Hosting utility, and that's set up via the project settings.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I can make a project using WcfSvcHost.exe and it works, but it doesn't solve my problem. I tried using "start external program" to actually host my WCF Service Application project in WcfSvcHost, and it does work, but when I try to add a reference to that project, it still tries to pick up the http:// address defined in the Servers section. Also, I can't change to a Service Library project for my main project, since in production I have to host in IIS.

Comment: Start the service in WcfSvcHost, then try to add a reference to the hosted URL.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I can do that, and it works, but I am still missing one piece of functionality- the ability to change methods exposed by the service and have them picked up by the client in the same solution without running external programs and having to Update Service Reference in VS. If there's no way of actually accomplishing that, then go ahead and submit an answer with the WcfSvcHost tip and I'll accept it. Either way, thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the service in WcfSvcHost, then try to add a reference to the hosted URL.

Unfortunately, the VS IDE has no technique to start services automatically, except for when you're debugging.

Also, you always need to update service references explicitly. You need to decide which of your changes are ready to be applied to which clients of your service. It would be bad to assume that all clients should be updated as soon as you make a change then compile your service.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a project, which you don't deploy, but only use during development, that [self-hosts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) the service.